# Angular js 6 405 (Method Not Allowed) in docker-compose

Tags: angular, docker-compose, angular6

I use docker-compose for dockerizing my project and I have
Php,mysql,nodej.js… 
You can see below all my sources code that can may have understand my issues

Code docker-compose:

```
    version: '2'

services:
   db:
     build: ./mysql
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     ports:
         - '3306:3306'
     environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=testDB
         - MYSQL_USER=pass
         - MYSQL_PASSWORD=devel
         - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
   phpmyadmin:
        build: ./phpmyadmin
        links: 
            - db:db
        ports:
            - '8001:80'
   php:
            build: ./php
            ports:
            - '80:80'
            restart: always
            volumes:
            - /home/samir2/www:/var/www/html
            depends_on:
            - db
   node.js:
        build: ./node.js
        ports:
            - '3000:3030'
        volumes:
        - /home/samir2/www:/var/www/html
volumes:
  db_data:
```

My web service worked perfectly with postman , when i tried to 
Adding some data into the web service it’s inserted in databases successfully.

[postman web service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MbEe.png)

But when I trying to use the request from angular 6

It’s can’t access in my server with “405 (Method Not Allowed)”

Code for my service user

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {User} from "../model/user.model";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  baseUrl: string = 'http://server/blog/public/api/register';

  createUser(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, user);
  }
}
```

[error message front angular.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUTKd.png)

my code add-user.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h2 class="text-center">Add User</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address:</label>
      <input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <input formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
      <input formControlName="lastName" placeholder="Last name" name="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and add-user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {UserService} from "../service/user.service";
import {first} from "rxjs/operators";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-user',
  templateUrl: './add-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-user.component.css']
})
export class AddUserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }

  addForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required]
    });

  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.userService.createUser(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.router.navigate(['list-user']);
      });
  }

}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: In your error image, it shows GET request and in your postman it shows POST. Can you post more related code.

Comment: how come it's GET methode and in my service user is post ( return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, user); ) ?

Comment: can you post your component.ts and html, where you used the service

Comment: yes it's done you can check

Comment: and when i tried to change method of my webservice to GET in message give zone.js:2969 POST blog/public/api/register 405 (Method Not Allowed)  it's the opposite i don't understand really ?!

Comment: console.log(data) in your onSubmit() method

Comment: Thanks :) it's works now , i had a problem with my fields form
 {user created: true}
user